# ¿Como oculto textbox al presionar un radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hola quiero ocultar los textbox cuando seleccione el radio button llamado administrativo . Y cuando seleccione conductor muestre los textboxs ..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has probado? Eso con un evento generado por el Checkbox tendria que ser suficiente, intenta añadir el código que hayas probado.

Comment: Estos check realizan un postback o lo quieres hacer del lado del cliente? Debes subir el código de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Hola, esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Para ocultar un text box por medio de los radio button puedes usar lo siguiente

```
   private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            txtComentario.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            txtComentario.Show();
        }
    }
```

Usas el evento de checkedCahnged del radio button luego preguntas si esta seleccionado o no y escondes y muestras el text box

Comment: Como sabes que lo desea hacer del lado del servidor? que es lo que ha intentado? Gracias por responder, pero hay que evitar dar respuestas a este tipo de preguntas que no cumplen con las normas del sitio. De este modo se intenta conservar la calidad de preguntas realizada. Saludos!

Comment: Mmm, no es mejor usar la propiedad `Visible`. Algo así como, `txtComentario.Visible = true`.

Comment: como lo implemento con un autopostback

Comment: Solo recordar que es WebForms, por si pensaban que es WinForms.